# Create Mongoose Schema Dynamically for e-commerce website in Node

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, admin

I would like to ask a question about a possible solution for an e-commerce database design in terms of scalability and flexibility.

We are going to use MongoDB and Node on the backend.

I included an image for you to see what we have so far. We currently have a **Products table** that can be used to add a product into the system. The interesting part is that we would like to be able to add different types of products to the system with varying attributes.

For example, in the admin management page, we could select a **Clothes item** where we should fill out a form with fields such as *Height, Length, Size* ... etc. The question is how could we model this way of structure in the database design?

What we were thinking of was creating tables such as **ClothesProduct** and many more and respectively connect the **Products table** to one of these. But we could have 100 different tables for the varying product types. We would like to add a product type dynamically from the admin management. Is this possible in Mongoose? Because creating all possible fields in the **Products table** is not efficient and it would hit us hard for the long-term.

[Database design snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSW3h.png)

Maybe we should just create separate tables for each unique product type and from the front-end, we would select one of them to display the correct form?

Could you please share your thoughts?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've got a mongoose backend that I've been working on since its inception about 3 years ago. Here some of my lessons:

- Mongodb is noSQL: By linking all these objects by ID, it becomes very painful to find all products of "Shop A": You would have to make many queries before getting the list of products for a particular shop (shop -> brand category -> subCategory -> product). Consider nesting certain objects in other objects (e.g. subcategories inside categories, as they are semantically the same). This will save immense loading times.
- Dynamically created product fields: We built a (now) big module that allows user to create their own databse keys & values, and assign them to different objects. In essence, it looks something like this:

```
SpecialFieldModel: new Schema({
   ...,
    key: String,
    value: String,
   ...,
   
})
```

this way, you users can "make their own products"

- Number of products: Mongodb queries can handle huge dataloads, so I wouldn't worry too much about some tables beings thousands of objects large.  However, if you want large reports on *all* the data, you will need to make sure your IDs are in the right place. Then you can use the [Aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) to construct big queries that might have to tie together multiple collectons in the db, and fetch the data in an efficient manner.
- Don't reference IDs in both directions, unless you don't know what you're doing: Saving a reference to category ID in subcatgories and vice-versa is incredibly confusing. Which field do you have to update if you want to switch subcategories? One or the other? Or both? Even with strong tests, it can be very confusing for new developers to understand "which direction the queries are running in" (if you are building a proudct that might have to be extended in the future). We've done both which has led to a few problems. However, those modules that saved references to upper objects (rather than lower ones), I found to be consistently more pleasant and simple to work with.
- created/updatedAt: Consider adding these fields to every single model & Schema. This will help with debugging, extensibility, and general features that you will be able to build in the future, which might otherwise be impossible. (`ProductSchema.set('timestamps', true);`)

Take my advice with a grain of salt, as I haven't designed most of our modules. But these are the sorts of things I consider as continue working on our applications.

Comment: Hi Michal, 

Thanks for your answer, I will make very good use of it. :) 

What I am going to do is store the IDs of the upper level models on the lower level models. For example, I keep categoryID in SubCategories, but remove the SubCategoryID array from Categories.

Could you please elaborate on the dynamic Schema addition, please? It sounds really good, but I am not sure where to start. And so to say, you found this the best solution for product type separation?

Comment: For "Custom Schema Addition", we have found that splitting our objects works well: Product, and ProductDraft. The draft specifies what the concrete object looks like, where one might add the custom schemas, nested in the drafts, that are then transferred to the concrete ones. Its confusing why there would be drafts, but it basically allows a dynamization/user specified concrete object. Example: draftSchema: {dynamicField: [{name: String, value: [String]}]} --> concrete: {dynamicField: [{name: "Prod1", value: [String]}]}. I'm not sure this is clear

Comment: Thank you very much for detailing your solution. :) I am just thinking, could we make it a bit simpler if we added a customOptions field in the Product table, which would be an array of key-value pairs and we would just populate it differently for each product?

Comment: Populating via Model.find().populate(...) is not very efficient, and cannot handle IDs from different collections. You might have to do something like [{entity: String, ID: ObjectId("a34fd...")}], fetch the approriate model, and only then search. However, I can't give you an exact implementation strategy: I don't know your requirements, budget, possible delverable deadlne, etc.